# Dynamically add subdir in a Qt Project File?

Tags: qt, plugins, project, qmake

I need to dynamically add folders into $SUBDIRS , just scan for some folders , and:

```
for file in plugin_dir
   if folder name ~ "^plugin-[A-Z]+$"
      SUBDIRS += $name
   fi
```

But how can i implement this in a .pro file ?

Comment: Are you talking about editing the .pro project file? If so, I suggest adding the tag `qmake`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this by using qmake's [system](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command) command.

Where we need non-trivial commands to be run, we write a script (we use Python, but any language would do) that we pass info into via command-line options, and that writes out the desired values we want out into a qmake variable.